# Azure doc db nested query

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

I have document schema like below in my collection

```
{
......
    Message :
    {
       Content : "E$XCV&*",
       Vehicles : [
         {
           Status : "",
           VehicleId : "veh1",
           ........
         },
         {
           Status : "",
           VehicleId : "veh2",
           ........
         },
         {
           Status : "",
           VehicleId : "veh1",
           ........
         },
         ............
       ]
    }
}
```

I need to update status for particular vehicle id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CosmosDb doesn't have a convenient client side API for modifying a specific property of a document like this. You need to retrieve the document and make the modification and then use `Upsert` to put the newly updated document in it's place.

Alternatively, you can do it on the server side using CosmosDb Stored Procedures which would allow to modify the doc in place.

Comment: True.. Finally I came up with a stored proc.. Thanks to ARRAY_CONTAINS() of doc db.